# is it possible to find which page and/or line number a given text was found using full text search and filestream?

Tags: search, sql-server-2012, full-text-search, filestream

I just started using the filestream and full text search technologies available on Microsoft Sql Server, I can index and search txt and pdf files, however, when I get the results I can't see the text, nor which page and/or line number that text was found inside the pdf for example, is it possible to at least retrieve the text from the document when a search is made? I believe it's not possible to return a "region" of text but maybe something I can use to look for in the file afterwards?

I'm trying to figure out the advantages of doing a search like this if I can't see the text that was found.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a lot of research I concluded it isn't possible to search for a given page on an indexed pdf, so I decided to use solr instead and index the information the way I need to search later